# Função para enviar dado AJAX?

Tags: ajax, funções

Estou tentando montar uma função para enviar um ajax, a função deve retornar meu resultado do ajax:

```
var url = localStorage.getItem("site");
var dataForm = new FormData(this);
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: url ,
    data: dataForm ,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(result)
    {
        if(result == null || result.length < 3 || result == "ok" || result == " ")
        {
            return "ok";
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error)
    {
        return error;
    }
});
```

Tentei com o código acima, alterando o `FormData` da linha 2 que será passado por parâmetro.

O retorno certamente será uma string, mas ao tentar pegar o retorno não consigo:

var retorno = sendAjax(this). // onde this é meu formulario

o `retorno` sempre vale `undefined`.
Já certifiquei que o ajax tem sim um retorno na função `success`

Qual seria o erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `$.ajax` é assíncrona: o resultado dela não está disponível quando ela termina de executar. Você precisa fazer a sua função (sendAjax) assíncrona também, recebendo uma função (*callback*) que será chamada quando o resultado estiver disponível. Algo semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
function sendAjax(dataForm, callback) {
    var url = localStorage.getItem("site");
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: url ,
        data: dataForm ,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(result)
        {
            if(result == null || result.length < 3 || result == "ok" || result == " ")
            {
                callback("ok");
            }
            else
            {
                callback(result);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error)
        {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
}

sendAjax(new FormData(this), function(retorno) {
    // Use o valor de `retorno` aqui
});
```